# Как исправить ошибку: ssh: connect to "" Connection timed out fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, gitlab

Связал свой локальный проект с репозиторием в гитлабе, теперь пытаюсь запушить в репозиторий свои файлы.
Если пробую: `git push origin main`, то выдаёт:

```
ssh: connect to host "тут мой реп" port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Если пробую: `git push 'подробно указываю путь с припиской https://'`, то выдаёт:

```
fatal: unable to access 'мой реп': Failed to connect to 'мой реп' port 2023 after 21068 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

Comment: `Связал свой локальный проект с репозиторием в гитлабе` - расшифруйте фразу

Comment: git remote add origin `путь к репозиторию на гитлабе без https://`

Comment: по инструкции нужно создать ssh ключ, отправить публичный в gitlab. что вы сделали для создания ключа? https://losst.pro/kak-polzovatsya-gitlab#5_SSH_ключи

Comment: Ваша ссылка оказалась полезной, но в решении проблемы не помогла. Однако сейчас всё успешно заработало, не пришлось ничего менять, просто чудо какое-то.